# How to use packages download from nuget on Mac (Mono)

Tags: c#, f#, mono, nuget

I tried to use nuget for downloading packages. For example, I'm trying to use [suave.io](http://suave.io) for web programming with F# on Mac.

With nuget (aliased as 'mono /bin/mono/nuget.exe'), I could download the packages.

```
nuget install Suave 
Attempting to resolve dependency 'FSharp.Core (≥ 3.1.2.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'FsPickler (≥ 1.0.7)'.
Installing 'FSharp.Core 3.1.2.1'.
Successfully installed 'FSharp.Core 3.1.2.1'.
Installing 'FsPickler 1.0.7'.
Successfully installed 'FsPickler 1.0.7'.
Installing 'Suave 0.24.0'.
Successfully installed 'Suave 0.24.0'.
```

The issue is that compared to brew that installs the package in /usr/local/Cellar, it downloads the package (library) in current directory.

What's the next step to use the downloaded library with Mono? Even better, is there a way to use the download and install the libraries from my F#/C# code easily?

Comment: Are you using an IDE?  There's a Nuget addin for both Xamarin Studio and MonoDevelop. https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin

Comment: why this is perfectly fine - you just can reference the downloaded dlls within your solutions/projects/fsi/whatever files.

Comment: I was just getting clarification so I could write an answer that applied.  Direct references are always an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments of the question, I could make the suave webserver working.

I copied the downloaded packages to the place where I collect nuget packages (`/bin/mono/`). Then, I made F# script (hello.fsx).

```ml
#r @"/bin/mono/Suave.0.24.0/lib/net40/Suave.dll"

open Suave                 // always open suave
open Suave.Http.Successful // for OK-result
open Suave.Web             // for config

web_server default_config (OK "Hello World!")
```

Running the code with `fsharpi hello.fsx` makes the web server working.